# How to flow the text anywhere in html

Tags: html, css, text

I want the text to be in the top of the arrow as of the figure shown below:

[image: fig]

The html entity of the arrow is `&#x27F6;`

can you please help me?

This is what I tried, but I want as of figure, arrow is also short as of this `&#x27F6;` entity.

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">MnO<sub>2</sub></div>
<div class="arrow">&#x27F6;</div>
```

Comment: Post your code and please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BarLevin I didn't know so I asked, whats wrong with my question? could you please mention that?

Comment: Post your code and show us what you did try

Comment: We are not here to just ”make” stuff for you, or give you tutorials. You need to start by explaining what _you_ tried so far. And at least show the basic HTML structure you have for this content so far.

Comment: @BarLevin  , I'm sorry for that. :( I've added what I tried.

Comment: @CBroe I'm sorry for not added what I tried, I forgot in rush. I have added that now. :(

Comment: _“arrow is also short”_ - well then start by increasing the font size, or _stretch_ it by applying a scale transformation.

Comment: @CBroe I used ```transform: scale(2, 1); 
  transform-origin: left;``` to stretch. Arrow is now working fine. what should I do for text? to fit it above it and at middle?

Comment: I’d start by wrapping both in an inline-block container element. The scaled element however will only influence the width of any ancestor by its original width, so you might need to involve a fixed width or some padding on either side here.

Comment: @CBroe I didn't get that. I would like to wrap them in span or sth because those arrow with text are to be joined with another texts.

Answer (score 2):

Look into [MathJax mhchem package](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/). It can let you writing chemical equations easily.

```js
window.MathJax = {
  TeX: {
    extensions: ["mhchem.js"]
  },
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [
      ['$', '$'],
      ["\\(", "\\)"]
    ]
  }
};
```

```css
.MathJax_CHTML {
  font-size: 30px !important;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
</script>
<p> $\xrightarrow{\text{$\ce{MnO2}$}}$</p>
<br />
<p> $\ce{A ->[catalyst] B}$</p>
```

Comment: do you know how can I converts equations written in word into MathJax's language for free?

Answer (score 0):

Here , this will work for you.

```html
<style>
  .text {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 12px
  }
  
  .arrow {
    transform: scale(4, 2);
    transform-origin: left;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <div class="text">MnO<sub>2</sub></div>
  <div class="arrow">&#x27F6;</div>

</body>
```

Comment: It is not aligned properly as of figure, :(

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the font size of the arrow and maybe slightly scale the width of the arrow-character by e. g. giving it's parent div something like

```
display:inline-block;
-webkit-transform:scale(3.0,1.0);
-moz-transform:scale(3.0, 1.0);
-ms-transform:scale(3.0, 1.0);
-o-transform:scale(3.0, 1.0);
transform:scale(3.0,1.0);
```

Will probably distort your arrowhead to ugly. If you want that exact ratio from text to arrow, you would have to use an appropriate image for the arrow.

Comment: and what should I do for text?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your question.